# ag-Grid row not deleting

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to delete a row from my ag-Grid like so:

```
let alertRow : RowNode = this.gridApi.getRowNode(rowIndex);
console.log(alertRow);
this.gridApi.updateRowData({remove: [alertRow]});
```

It gives me this error:

> ag-Grid: could not find data item as object was not found

I can see in console the `RowNode` is the correct node and exists.  I am also able to use `updateRowData()` to add new rows in fine but trying to remove gives this error.

I am using ag-Grid in Angular 6 component.

Why is removing not working?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace `updateRowData({remove:[alerRow]})` by

`updateRowData({remove:[alertRow.data]}))`

> updated [doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#removing-rows)
>
> ... If you are not using ID's, then the grid **will match the rows based on object reference.**

Comment: Their document is shit it says `remove: RowNode[];` clearly array of `RowNodes`

Comment: sent them the request, now it's in the backlog
`AG-3087 - RowNodeTransaction interface misnamed in documentation`

Comment: by using this approach is getting deleted for me, but when i m adding rows again on the same rowindex and deleting again its saying ,cannot read property data is undefined.

Comment: @RuchiGupta to be able to help you I need some more details, could you provide a plinkr or stackblitz link for testing?

Comment: @un.spike I have posted a new question for this issue:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777716/dynamically-adding-and-deleting-row-in-empty-ag-grid-first-time-row-is-getting-d

Comment: clearly documentation needs an update is not RowNode[] as someone else pointed out. This was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you use vue.js, you can use this lines of codes:

1. Get select row, `const selectedRow = this.gridApi.getFocusedCell()`
2. Get node by select row const node = `this.gridApi.getRowNode(selectedRow.rowIndex)`
3. ApplyTransaction to remove the node by data of the node. `this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ remove: [node.data] })`

Comment: It won't let me edit, but "const node =" should be inside the code tag for #2.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure this is the right place/way to add on to [un.spike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52655449/5174670), but if you're using the [getSelectedNodes](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#selection) method to obtain the data you're trying to delete, the syntax is a little different (requires indexing into the selected node).

(Both assume you're using single row selection)

**getSelectedNodes**

```
const selectedNode = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: [selectedNode[0].data] });
```

And, for "completeness" sake,
**getSelectedRows** (even though the API suggests using `getSelectedNodes`)

```
const selectedRow = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: selectedRow });
```