# React.js: How to delete row from an ag grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using react and ag grid. i want to delete row from the grid.

here is the code

```
onButtonClick = e => {
  this.setState({
    visible: true
  });
  const selectedNodes = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
  let deletedRow = selectedNodes;
  e.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: [deletedRow] });
};
```

when i used this instead of e, i got : **ag-Grid: could not find data item as object was not found**

```html
<button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>delete</button>;
<AgGridReact
  onGridReady={params => (this.gridApi = params.api)}
  rowSelection="multiple"
  columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
  rowData={this.state.rowData}
  defaultColDef={{
    editable: true
  }}
/>;
```

console.log(deletedRow)

> Unable to display error. Open your browser's console to view
>
> g-Grid: could not find data item as object was not found
>
> Error: Object too large to inspect. Open your browser console to view.
>    at Object. (preview-2e4d276ba818b5932108b.js:1)
>       at JSON.stringify ()
>       at P.r.**error** (preview-2e4d276ba818b5932108b.js:1)
>       at P (preview-2e4d276ba818b5932108b.js:1)
>       at preview-2e4d276ba818b5932108b.js:1
>       at Array.map ()
>       at Q (preview-2e4d276ba818b5932108b.js:1)
>       at console. [as log] (preview-2e4d276ba818b5932108b.js:1)
>       at App._this.onButtonClick (index.js:44)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336)
>
> [RowNode] 0: RowNode childrenMapped: {} selectable: true
>   **objectId: 1 alreadyRendered: true highlighted: null selected: true mainEventService: EventService {allSyncListeners: Map(75),
>   allAsyncListeners: Map(56), globalSyncListeners: Set(0),
>   globalAsyncListeners: Set(1), asyncFunctionsQueue: Array(0), …}
>   gridOptionsWrapper: GridOptionsWrapper {propertyEventService:
>   EventService, domDataKey: "__AG_0.09475464623441865", layoutElements:
>   Array(5), gridOptions: {…}, columnController: ColumnController, …}
>   selectionController: SelectionController {eventService: EventService,
>   rowModel: ClientSideRowModel, gridOptionsWrapper: GridOptionsWrapper,
>   columnApi: ColumnApi, gridApi: GridApi, …} columnController:
>   ColumnController {primaryHeaderRowCount: 1, secondaryHeaderRowCount:
>   0, secondaryColumnsPresent: false, gridHeaderRowCount: 1,
>   displayedLeftColumns: Array(0), …} valueService: ValueService
>   {initialised: true, gridOptionsWrapper: GridOptionsWrapper,
>   expressionService: ExpressionService, columnController:
>   ColumnController, eventService: EventService, …} rowModel:
>   ClientSideRowModel {gridOptionsWrapper: GridOptionsWrapper,
>   columnController: ColumnController, filterManager: FilterManager,
>   $scope: undefined, selectionController: SelectionController, …}
>   context: Context {beanWrappers: {…}, componentsMappedByName: {…},
>   destroyed: false, contextParams: {…}, logger: Logger} valueCache:
>   ValueCache {cacheVersion: 2, gridOptionsWrapper: GridOptionsWrapper,
>   active: false, neverExpires: false} columnApi: ColumnApi
>   {columnController: ColumnController} gridApi: GridApi
>   {detailGridInfoMap: {…}, immutableService: ImmutableService,
>   csvCreator: CsvCreator, excelCreator: null, rowRenderer: RowRenderer,
>   …} group: false master: false expanded: false canFlower: false parent:
>   RowNode {childrenMapped: null, selectable: true, __objectId: 0,
>   alreadyRendered: false, highlighted: null, …} level: 0 data: Date:
>   "2020-03-13" Price1: 31.72 Price2: 33 Price3: 0.929 Price4: 0.907
>   Price5: 1.097 Price6: 1.147 Price7: 1.175 Price8: 1.122 Price9: 1.272
>   Price10: 0.977 Price11: 0.293
>   __proto**: Object id: "0" childrenAfterFilter: undefined allChildrenCount: null firstChild: true lastChild: false childIndex: 0
>   uiLevel: 0 oldRowTop: undefined rowTop: 0 rowHeight: 28
>   rowHeightEstimated: false rowIndex: 0 eventService: EventService
>   {allSyncListeners: Map(16), allAsyncListeners: Map(8),
>   globalSyncListeners: Set(0), globalAsyncListeners: Set(0),
>   asyncFunctionsQueue: Array(0), …}
>   **proto**: Object length: 1
>   **proto**: Array(0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ag-Grid row not deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654846/ag-grid-row-not-deleting)

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem by replace

```
const selectedNodes = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
```

with

```
var selectedNodes = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to call `e` instead of you can call directly

```
this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: [deletedRow] })
```

Comment: I got : ag-Grid: could not find data item as object was not found

Comment: @AlaaAlarfaj pls prepare plinkr or stackblitz example

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: [deletedRow] })`

by

```
this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: [deletedRow.data] })
```

Comment: still got: ag-Grid: could not find data item as object was not found