# Dynamically adding and deleting row in empty ag-grid,first time row is getting deleted, second time throwing error

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Initially i am displaying empty grid with header names. on click of add button new empty row should be added with delete icon.I am able to dynamically add row ag-grid.First time if i delete row  after adding, its getting deleted, but second time its giving me below error..

Second time, its giving me error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Method getting calling on adding row:-

```
createNewRowData() {
  let newData = {
    tableName: '',
    schemaName: '',
    columnName: '',
    condition: ''
  };
  console.log('newDATA', newData);
  this.setState({
    newCount:this.state.newCount+1
})
}
onAddRow() {
  let newItem = this.createNewRowData.bind(this);
  let res = this.state.gridOptions.api.updateRowData({add: [newItem]});
}
```

method called on delete:-

```
methodFromParent(cell) {
  const rowNode = this.state.gridOptions.api.getRowNode(cell.rowIndex);
  this.state.gridOptions.api.updateRowData({remove: [rowNode.data]});
  this.state.newCount--;
}
```

my Custom cell renderer for delete which appears for each row which i am using in my colDefs:-

```
export default class DeleteButtonRenderer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.invokeParentMethod = this.invokeParentMethod.bind(this);
  }
  invokeParentMethod(e) {
    this.props.context.componentParent.methodFromParent(this.props.node);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <a
          style={{ height: 20, lineHeight: 0.5 }}
          onClick={this.invokeParentMethod}
        >
          <i className="far fa-trash-alt fa-2x" />
        </a>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, method `methodFromParent(rowIndex)` - has `rowIndex` input property, but it doesn't belong to `index`, you are using `e.target.id` in this method `.methodFromParent(+e.target.id)` - as `index` - that's why you faced with issue.

on `RowNode` interface, you can access `rowIndex`

```
/** The index of this node in the grid, only valid if node is displayed in the grid, otherwise it should be ignored as old index may be present */
rowIndex: number;
```

On custom renderer, you are able to access full `node` data (`RowNode` interface), so just pass `node.rowIndex` to `invokeParentMethod` function.

*It could work for first time cuz `id` could be same as `index`, but anyway for more details, I need to get your real code, so if you are able, provide plinkr or stackblitz.*

> Update

*So, I dived in deep in your sample and here what I found:*

First, `this.createNewRowData.bind(this)` - is a reference binding, which need to be used ***implicit***, but it's not required here, and you need to execute it directly (***explicit***), **try `console.log(newItem)` for clarity**, you will get a `function` reference.

Second, `createNewRowData` - doesn't return a new object, and when you will fix a function exectution like `let newItem = this.createNewRowData();` it would be `undefined`.

Third, if you are planning to use `empty` objects in the grid, then `updateRowData({remove: [rowNode.data]});` wouldn't work and you need to use different way for `remove`, as an example - `selection`. 
[*answer why*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654846/ag-grid-row-not-deleting/52655449#52655449)

customRenderer

```
invokeParentMethod(){
    this.props.node.setSelected(true);
    this.props.context.componentParent.methodFromParent();
}
```

parent (main grid component)

```
methodFromParent(){
    let selectedData = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
    this.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: selectedData });
};
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/gjThOlqO2TFRioe8)

Comment: Changed the method like this:-invokeParentMethod(e) {
    this.props.context.componentParent.methodFromParent(this.props.node)
  }

  render() {
   // const {rowIndex} = this.props.node;
    return (
      <span><a  style={{height: 20, lineHeight: 0.5}} onClick={this.invokeParentMethod}><i className="far fa-trash-alt fa-2x"></i></a></span>
    );  still same error.

Comment: @RuchiGupta pls update a question cuz I can't understand what is written here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.I have one more question, as we are entering data in row, dynamically how rowdata will be updated

Comment: @RuchiGupta Create another question and i will try to help